# JUnit: compare the contents of two unordered text files

Tags: java, junit, comparison, file-comparison

I would like to write a unit test to compare the text file output of a method against an expected value.  However, I prefer not to constrain the test to have a precise line ordering requirement in the comparison.  Is there an elegant way to write such a test in Java/Junit or must I write my own logic for this task?

Thanks!

Setjmp

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? It's kind of vague. For example, does the file has a pre-defined format? What does its content look like?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you convert the return value of the method under test and the expected value into two lists of strings with one string per line.

The two lists can then easily be compared using [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html). I find it a great tool when it comes to testing assertions on lists:

```
@Test
public void shouldContainSameLines() throws IOException {
  List<String> actualLines = ClassUnderTest.loadText();

  List<String> expectedLines = asList("Hello", "World", "Goodbye");
  assertThat(actualLines)
      .containsAll(expectedLines);
}
```

`assertThat()` is the entry point into AssertJ's fluent API. Based on the type of the method passed to `assertThat()` sensible verifications are offered. In this case I used `containsAll()` to test that `actualLines` contains all lines which are in `expectedLines` in any order.

Comment: Alternatively, you might point out using JUnit assertThat() with the corresponding hamcrest matcher (I am sure there is a similar one).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(T... items)` for this purpose.

```
@Test
public void testSomeMethod_shouldReadFileProperly() {
    String contents = "foo\nbar"; // change to actual method call
    assertThat(Arrays.asList(contents.split("\n"), 
            containsInAnyOrder("bar", "foo"));
}
```